# How to notify when send a file in SendBird

Tags: java, parse-platform, chat, sendbird

I just have a problem with SendBird. When I sent a message, the SendBird callback to onMessagingChannelUpdated, but when I sent a file, the callback didn't work.

I already RegisterNotificationHandler for SendBird.

```
SendBird.registerNotificationHandler(new SendBirdNotificationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMessagingChannelUpdated(MessagingChannel messagingChannel) { } });
```

Please give me an idea of any suggestions.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

SendBird is working on this issue and onMessagingChannelUpdated callback will be called for files too. It should be released soon. 
We will let you know as soon as it gets released.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I will waiting your answer.